# QT adding compiler

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I have QT 5.3.1 for Android (Windows), downloaded from http://qt-project.org/downloads with minGW 4.8.
Now I want to use MinGW 4.9 compiler.

To do so, I download mingw-w64 build [i686, posix, dwarf], and install it to separate folder.
Then, in QT creator, I add compiler in the "Build&Run" options.

Now when I compile something with `-std=c++1y` flag, in release mode - my program crashes at once (even window does not appear), and in debug mode I get :

`During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139`

What I do wrong?

Comment: where did you download that build. Is it 32bit or 64bit? What exception handling does it use(SEH, DWARF, SJLJ)? Qt windows builds from qt-project.org provide only DWARF 32bit MinGW builds.

Comment: I use i686 posix dwarf from here http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php.

Comment: Possibly, you miss some libraries. Just google error code.

Comment: can you just download qt and qt creator build with mingw 4.9? go here http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtx64/

Comment: @Nazar554 I definitely could download it, if only it was 4.9, not 4.8.2 (that link leads to 4.8.2 mingw build)

Comment: @tower120 it is 4.9. look in mingw49 subfolder

Comment: @Nazar554 Do they have iOS / Android builds?

Comment: @tower120 you can use qt creator from qt-project.org. just install android toolkits you need, then setup kits for their builds. just follow the install instructions.

Comment: @Nazar554 So, I'll need to QT's - one for Windows builds, one for Android?

Comment: @tower120 Yes. I have 4 Qt builds: 2 for android (armv5, armv7) and 2 for windows (mingw-w64 32bit sjlj and 64bit seh)(compact ones). You can use the package manager to choose what toolchains to install when you use Qt from qt-project.org.

Comment: @Nazar554 Why you need 2 builds for Android? I use single Digia's build for all android's (v5, v7, x86). Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: @tower120 i meant package manager components. there is one for armv5 and one for armv7. You can see them using MaintenanceTool.exe in Qt install directory.

Comment: @Nazar554 So - you have one QT creator, and 4 components?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58437/discussion-between-nazar554-and-tower120).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Qt build from [qtx64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtx64). It is built using MinGW 4.9 and has dwarf,seh,sjlj builds for x86/x64.

To use it you can create Qt Creator kit with it. You can use Qt Creator from [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org) but It should be configured like this:

[Configuration images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WywZg.jpg)

Comment: I found that ANGLE -builds not work for me (applications closes with SEGFAULT). And according to your settings you use "compact" build, with OpenGL. Could you, please, try build without postfix? This `qt-5.3.1-x86-mingw490r2-sjlj.exe` , for example

Comment: @tower120 can you try updating your GPU drivers?

Comment: Last Nvidia driver is installed. Besides Digia's ANGLE version works fine.